# No Errors Global Ban

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots

I don't know what is wrong with it, to me everything looks fine I get no errors in the console but when I try to global ban someone it doesn't even ban them from any of the servers!

```
@commands.command()
async def gban(self, ctx, user: discord.User, *, reason=None):
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="<< Management Team")
    if role in ctx.author.roles:
        if reason == None:
                reasonem = discord.Embed(title="Specify a reason for logging purposes")
                await ctx.send(embed=reasonem)
                return
        for guild in bot.guilds:
            await guild.ban(user, reason=reason)
    else:
        await ctx.message.delete()
        em = discord.Embed(title="Permissions Required!", description=f"{ctx.author.name} You do not have the required Permissions to use this command", color=discord.Colour.red())
        await ctx.send(embed=em)
```

Comment: No the `async def` is not on the wrong indention I just noticed that but In my bot code that is not indented like that

Comment: My psychic debugging skills tells me that `reason` is `None`, which causes it to enter the `if reason == None` block, which contains a `return`, which causes the loop which does the bans not to be executed. If you learn to use a debugger to step through the code, you can find these sorts of logic errors pretty easily.

Comment: That's the thing @KenWhite I put a reason and I even rewrote the code to just say the global ban without the reasons etc but it still didn't work

Comment: I can't answer questions about code you rewrote that I can't see. I can clearly see the problem with the code you've posted here, and I've already explained the problem with that code. The `return` means that the code exits at that point and returns to the calling location, which means that none of the code below that point is executed, which means that the code that does the ban is never reached. You can add some debugging `print` lines in your code to trace what's being executed, or use a debugger to step through the code.

Comment: Thank you @KenWhite I found my mistake and I feel very stupid for posting this Stack Overflow post I fixed my issue with a `else` statement right after the return to first check if the reason is none and if the reason is something else it will execute the global ban! Thank you for your reply and I am sorry for wasting you time to a simple easy fix! ♥️ From wolf

Comment: You're welcome. You can always delete the question if you've figured out the issue, unless you think that sharing the solution will benefit others, in which case you can write an answer yourself in the space below that is provided for that purpose - see [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I let a simple error affect my code in which I only specified the `if` statement on reason and didn't give it a `else` statement if a reason was provided

```
@commands.command()
async def gban(self, ctx, user: discord.User, *, reason=None):
     role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="<< Management Team")
     if role in ctx.author.roles:
                 if reason == None:
                    reasonem = discord.Embed(title="Specify a reason for logging purposes")
                    await ctx.send(embed=reasonem)
                    return
                 else:
                    for guild in bot.guilds:
                        await guild.ban(user, reason=reason)
     else:
         await ctx.message.delete()
         em = discord.Embed(title="Permissions Required!", description=f"{ctx.author.name} You do not have the required Permissions to use this command", color=discord.Colour.red())
         await ctx.send(embed=em)
```